# Search, compare and paste data between two excel sheets

Tags: excel

Is there any capability in Excel to compare different spreadsheets?

My task is as follows:

- I have an original file with an article number as well as a corresponding column (e.g. letter).
- I have a new spreadsheet where the article numbers are in a different order.

`Original File`

```
Article Number / Letter
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
```

`New File`

```
Article Number / Letter
3 ?
2 ?
1 ?
4 ?
5 ?
```

Goal: I would like to copy the letter values from the original file depending on the article number.

Hence, I am looking for a function to do the following:

- For a article number in the new file, search through the B-column in the original file
- In case the article number match, copy the neighbouring letter to the new file.

Is this possible in excel? I am not sure if I need to use conditional formatting or VLookup. My work-around would be to sort the original sheet according to the new one and copy the whole column.

Best,
rhuzh

[Search and Paste neighbouring cell value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g5HH.png)

Comment: This is very easy with VLOOKUP provided the article number is to the left of the letter you want returned. If it's on the right you can use XLOOKUP() or, if you don't have that on your version of Excel, INDEX/MATCH. Read up in the function you want to deploy and you'll be done in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub DictionaryTest()
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim rgsource As Range, rgDest As Range, I As Long
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set rgsource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Dim lr As Long: lr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 0 To lr - 1
        Dict.Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(I, 0).Value, Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(I, 1).Value
    Next
    Set rgDest = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    lr = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 0 To lr - 1
        If Dict.Exists(rgDest.Offset(I, 0).Value) Then rgDest.Offset(I, 1).Value =  Dict(rgDest.Offset(I, 0).Value)
    Next
    Set Dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

There is other ways but this way is very easy to understand